# Insert timestamp in row when formula result changes in the same row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to add a timestamp when a particular cell returns TRUE. With help from this community, I was able to modify the code below. It works perfectly if I type in TRUE. However, when a formula's result returns TRUE, it does not work. I must be doing something wrong.

Here is the code:

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if( s.getName() == "Campaign" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    if( r.getColumn() == 17 ) { //checks the column
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 10);
        if( r.getValue() === true)
            nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show the formula. P.S. instead of `getActiveCell()` on an `onEdit` function usually is better to use range property from the edit event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `onEdit(e)` only runs when the user *hand edits* the spreadsheet, and no events get triggered when a formula result changes.

Your description suggests that you have a formula cell in column `Q` in every row, and the value in that cell changes when *other* cells in the row are edited.

To insert a timestamp, you will need to make the `onEdit(e)` function read the value in the formula cell in column `Q` rather than the value in the cell that was edited. Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Campaign'
    || sheet.getRange('Q' + e.range.rowStart).getValue() !== true) {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange('AA' + e.range.rowStart)
    .setValue(new Date())
    .setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
}
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I am trying to achieve! Thanks for the explanation! it worked perfectly. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but believe me, I clicked that button. I'll re-read this a few dozen times to wrap my head around it. But for now the sheet works! Thanks again!

Comment: thanks! I still can't upvote, but just marked as accepted. Thanks again!